# Laravel - Change directory paths

Tags: apache, laravel, laravel-4

I have a domain hosted by one.com, and I have the following directories:

```
/webpage.com/httpd.private
/webpage.com/httpd.www
/webpage.com/tmp
```

The public webspace is in httpd.www and the private home folder is in httpd.private.

How would I configure laravel to use httpd.www as the "public" part of the app, and httpd.private to store the "vendor, bootstrap, app" folders?

Best regards,
Oyvind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change two files

#### public/index.php (new `httpd.www/index.php`)

```
require __DIR__.'/../httpd.private/bootstrap/autoload.php';
// ...
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../httpd.private/bootstrap/start.php';
```

#### bootstrap/paths.php (new `httpd.private/bootstrap/paths.php`)

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../httpd.www',
```

And obviously you need to move the files so it looks like

```
- httpd.private
--- app
--- bootstrap
--- vendor
--- artisan
--- composer.json
--- ...

- httpd.www
--- index.php
--- .htaccess
--- ...
```